# How do I interpret regression coefficients with autocorrelated residuals?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima

I am building a regression model of time series data in R, where my primary interest is the coefficients of the independent variables. The data exhibit strong seasonality with a trend.

[image: Original data]

The model looks good, with four of the six regressors significant:
[image: Model]

Here are the OLS residuals:
[image: Residuals]

I used auto.arima to select the sARIMA structure, and it returns the model (0,1,1)(1,1,0)[12].

```
fit.ar <- auto.arima(at.ts, xreg = xreg1, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
summary(fit.ar)

Series: at.ts 
ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
          ma1    sar1      v1       v2      v3       v4         v5
      -0.7058  0.3974  0.0342  -0.0160  0.0349  -0.0042  -113.4196
s.e.   0.1298  0.2043  0.0239   0.0567  0.0555   0.0333   117.1205

sigma^2 estimated as 3.86e+10:  log likelihood=-458.13
AIC=932.26   AICc=936.05   BIC=947.06

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set 7906.896 147920.3 103060.4 0.1590107 3.048322 0.1150526
```

My question is this: based on the parameter estimates and s.e. of the regressors, I believe that none of them are significant - is this correct, and if so, what does it imply if my goal is to interpret the relative importance of these predictors as opposed to forecasting?

Any other advice relative to the process of building this model is welcome and appreciated.

Here are the ACF and PACF for the residuals:

[image: ACF-PACF]

```
> durbinWatsonTest(mod.ols, max.lag=12)
 lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value
   1     0.120522674     1.6705144   0.106
   2     0.212723044     1.4816530   0.024
   3     0.159828108     1.5814771   0.114
   4     0.031083831     1.8352377   0.744
   5     0.081081308     1.6787808   0.418
   6    -0.024202465     1.8587561   0.954
   7    -0.008399949     1.7720761   0.944
   8     0.040751905     1.6022835   0.512
   9     0.129788310     1.4214391   0.178
  10    -0.015442379     1.6611922   0.822
  11     0.004506292     1.6133994   0.770
  12     0.376037337     0.7191359   0.000
 Alternative hypothesis: rho[lag] != 0
```

Comment: It looks like some of the t statistics are favorable (ma1, sar1, v1). Also, could you add to the post some information on how autocorrelated the residuals are, such as the Durbin-Watson statistic? They don't look that autocorrelated. If you do believe there is still autocorrelation, add another autocorrelation term to the arima and check how the AIC changes.

Comment: do you have acf/pacf of residuals? why do you think they're autocorrelated?

Comment: Added ACF/PACF for the residuals of the OLS model, as well as DW statistics. It should be noted that v6 in the OLS model is a dummy seasonal variable (0/1 marking the month of interest), which I excluded from the xreg in auto.arima in favor of letting it decide the seasonality structure. I'm sensing that the opinion so far is that sARIMA is not necessary, which confuses me because looking at the original data it sure looks like an obvious candidate for ARIMA errors. Perhaps I'm making this harder than it needs to be?

Comment: @Geoffrey, your residuals do not show any obvious autocorrelation, which is not surprising since you used auto.ARIMA. so the model looks fine in this regard. your variables dont seem to explain anything in the model.

Comment: @Aksakal, those are the autocorrelations for the OLS model, not auto.arima. Have I misunderstood your request in that regard?

Comment: @Geoffrey, whatever the autocorrelations, they're benign. I thought you ran the ARIMA model. maybe I'm confused. If you ran OLS, and got these nice residuals, then i'd stick to OLS, as long as your coefficients look good.

Comment: @Aksakal, my apologies for the confusion. I ran an OLS model, THEN an ARIMA model to incorporate the autocorrelation structure of the errors. The first three plots refer to the OLS model. I guess I'm surprised that this data _isn't_ autocorrelated...

Comment: @Geoffrey, you see the peak at 12 in your ACF? that's the seasonality, the only obvious issue. I would try first OLS with the seasonal dummy. start with monthly dummies, then try to reduce the number of dummies, you may end up with just one month dummy. e.g. in financial series, you often see jumps around the tax season in April, so a single dummy takes care of it in many cases

Comment: @Aksakal: So the residuals aren't autocorrelated, but the spike at 12 shows that (yearly) seasonality isn't being handled well? Geoffrey: Your graphs refer to the residuals, which gives you an idea if your model is missing some factor over time. The data itself is probably autocorrelated, but your variables account for that. At least that's my understanding of things.

Comment: @Wayne, as I wrote, peak 12 is not necessarily SAR(12), it could just be one month in the year, such as December

Comment: @Aksakal: Thanks. I started my comment before your comment about the single month showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be certain, the residual plot does not demonstrate autocorrelation. If you did want to visually describe the extent of autocorrelation in these data, I think a variogram would be a much better descriptive tool. Nonetheless, autocorrelation is present in these data based on your understanding of the time series and your belief that the predictors in your model do not adequately handle the extent of residual variance due to autocorrelation that they could. An example of when that might not be the case is in clinical trials with adaptive dosing where the dosage is based on severity of disease, so you make the time series of subsequent maladies conditionally independent by adjusting for the dosage.

Nonetheless, at any point if there is unmeasured correlation in the data, the interpretation of the coefficients remains exactly the same. The least squares regression slope is still a measure of expected difference in outcomes comparing a unit difference in exposures/regressors. What you *lose* by ignoring correlation is efficiency/validity of inference. Your standard errors can be inflated or shrunk, so it's the confidence intervals that are messed up. Of course, if you accurately identify the correlation structure, you can iteratively estimate correlation and parameters, and obtain the BLUE which gives valid inference. This is all detailed in Seber & Lee.

What's not in Seber & Lee is that if you use robust standard errors, these will give you correct inference even if the correlation structure is misspecified. The data could be AR-1, you can specify independence, and you still get valid inference... you just lose a little efficiency relative to estimating robust standard errors with the correct correlation structure.

Comment: My concern is precisely that I can not trust my confidence interval for the parameter estimates. The estimates themselves do not worry me, but my goal is to understand their relative significance (or lack thereof). I wish to obtain s.e.'s which leverage the autocorrelation I suspect to be present, thus the SARIMA structured model. The problem (which may simply be my lack of understanding) is that this structure tells me that none of the predictor variables are significant. This may be true, but it is surprising and I want to validate the process and conclusions I've reached.

Comment: Based on the lack of autocorrelation in the residual plot, would you conclude the OLS regression is an acceptable model for this data, where acceptable means robust s.e. for the parameter estimates?

Comment: I did not say that there is no autocorrelation. But I would never produce a residual plot to describe autocorrelation since I can't trust my eyeballs. (A variogram is a much better tool). You asked about the interpretation of the parameters. Since the parameter estimates unbiased, the interpretation remains the same: difference in outcome for unit difference in exposure. A linear regression with robust standard errors is a perfectly valid way to address this and obtain correct confidence intervals.

Comment: But are the s.e.'s robust in this situation? Or are you saying that a variogram is necessary to find out?

Comment: You should read about GEE, robust standard errors, and OLS to catch up. But no, `lm` output is not robust. You need the `sandwich` package.

Comment: Thanks Adam. The Newey-West correction seems to fit the bill for generating robust standard errors for my data.

Comment: I read the paper on NW SE estimators. Apparently, "Newey-West" estimators are yet another derivation of sandwich based SEs. It is NOT a correction, though. But it seems like you've mostly come to the same conclusion that I recommended.